# ubuntu grub2 install failed - fresh install

Tags: grub2

I am installing Ubuntu with Secure boot disabled and fast boot disabled yet grub2 is failing to get installed.
It's a clean install.
Please help!

Comment: what error are you getting, there are many ways an install can fail.  please add more detail

Comment: the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader the system will not boot

Comment: ah, it is failing during install?  does the instaler support a commandline option?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I've been seeing this error more and more recently, but there are multiple possible causes. Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are installing efi mode. I had this problem with my current computer. the issue wasn't with grub-install but rather update-grub, thus the config file for grub is not created.

if the installer has a command line option at the bottom it will make this a lot easier. since you can go back to install grub after making this change. otherwise you will have to finish without installing grub then use a live CD to fix the problem and install grub.

the file /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware is a script for adding the system uefi console to the grub menu. It errors out.

I edited mine to read:

> set -e
>
> gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2
>
> cat << EOF
>
> menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
>
> fwsetup
>
> }
>
> EOF

then updated grub.

if you can make this change without leaving the installer, go back to install grub and it should work.

If not then it becomes more complicated but can still be done. click finish the install with out grub.Boot from the live CD and make a file named "target" in the home directory then open a terminal there (right click-->actions-->open terminal). Verify the drive and partition numbers for you install to use bellow.

then execute the following commands:

> mount /dev/sda2 target
>
> mount /dev/sda1 target/boot/efi
>
> sudo chroot target
>
> sudo update-grub